# Magento2 acl xml equivalent of magento1x

Tags: magento2

I need the equivalent api xml in Magento2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<api>
    <resources>
        <testmodule_product translate="title" module="module1">
            <model>module1/api</model>
            <title>MyModule API</title>
            <acl>module1/product</acl>
            <methods>
                <get translate="title" module="module1">
                    <title>Get products by limit</title>
                    <method>getProduct</method>
                </get>
                <get_update_queue_size translate="title" module="module1">
                    <title>Get Product Update Count</title>
                    <method>getProductUpdateCount</method>
                </get_update_queue_size>
            </methods>
        </testmodule_product>
    </resources>

    <resources_alias>
        <product>testmodule_product</product>
    </resources_alias>

    <v2>
        <resources_function_prefix>
            <product>module1Product</product>
        </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <module1 translate="title" module="module1">
                <title>MyModule</title>
                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                <product translate="title" module="module1">
                    <title>module1</title>
                </product>
            </module1>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</api>
</config>
```

The above acl.xml is in Magento1, need the equivalent in Magento2x

Comment: what exactly you wants to do for magento2?

Comment: Im trying to sync the clients product catalog via SOAP API request when any changes are made from client on product details, which will be sent to my custom search engine server... For the above xml, i have implemented the interface, for <acl> <resources> and <resources_alias>, i needed the equivalent of Mage2x

Comment: Also i want "MyModule" and "module1" to be displayed under admin-> User roles-> Role resources