# Custom webapi attribute explanation

Tags: magento2

I need explanation for the different attributes used in webapi.xml in magento2.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route url="/V1/product" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\ProductGetInterface" method="getProduct"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Vendor_Module::product" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Like what does **route url**, **service class** and **resource ref** mean?

What value do they have? How to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route url specify the url of your call in your case its V1/product so after your store url you need to hit this url.
If suppose we are doing sum of two prodcts and my **webapi.xml** is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

    <route url="/V1/calculator/add/:num1/:num2" method="GET">
        <service class="Test\Calculator\Api\CalculatorInterface" method="add"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

I will hit url,`http://10.16.16.190/magentoce27/index.php/rest/V1/calculator/add/1/2`

where route url matches url and paramerters as above,

Now, service class defines API Interface for the purpose of method declaration for example,

```
<?php

namespace Test\Calculator\Api;

interface CalculatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Add two numbers.
     *
     * @param int $num1
     * @param int $num2
     * @return int
     */
    public function add($num1, $num2);
}

?>
```

If you get a token with a customer username/password, you can only access API methods with `<resource ref="self"></resource>` or `<resource ref="anonymous"></resource>`. The `<resource ref="anonymous"></resource>` methods can be called without any authorization.

Comment: Thanks RJ07, can you please tell whats 'rest' http://10.16.16.190/magentoce27/index.php/rest/V1/calculator/add/1/2 in ur url

Comment: And is route url can be given any name right? since we are using only in URl? Does it need to match with the method name ?

Comment: I suppose u refered this link https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/ in ur explanation! Here in AlanKent\CalculatorWebService\Api\Data\PointInterface, is Data\PointInterface really required in our custom module

Comment: Yes When I was creating example earlier before I followed this link. Its helpful

Comment: I see many places they use:   use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface; is it required in custom module

Comment: These search criteria applies to all API classes/interfaces which implements the method: getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)

For search APIs that invoke a *Repository::getList(SearchCriteriaInterface *) call, the searchCriteria must be specified in the URL of the GET request.

Comment: for first question, In URL rest specifies that call is using rest API

Comment: Ok, if my function is something like getProduct($page,$limit), do i need Api/Data/Interfacename (say PointInterface) and use getter and setter again ?  like setProduct...

Comment: Well in that case I need to dig deeper. Yet I have not explored much on it. I will surely let you know as I get information with this.

Comment: Sure RJ07, tysm :)

Comment: i need help for this webapi , on this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126315/magento2-acl-xml-equivalent-of-magento1x  @RJ07

Comment: Hi RJ07, i need suggestion on this Model resource, data not getting inserted problem, i have posted here....http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126819/unable-to-insert-data-into-custom-table-using-model-collection

Answer (score 0):

**resource ref** means who can access my API. (Guest user, Admin, Customer)

**Route url** specify the url of your call.

**service class** defines API Interface.

Comment: http://localhost/m233/rest/all/V1/wishlistapi/1/2   Why "all" parameter gets added in rest web api ?